# Iteration run faster for "even teams" code

Tags: java, android, performance, for-loop, iteration

I am coding to create two "even teams" based on the players' scores (puntajes).

The algorithm runs through the array of players and compares the score of each one to get a minimum difference and then sorts players into two arrays, one for each team.

**Here is my code:**

```
if (listaDeJugadores.size() == 6) 
//In this case I'm looking for a 6 player array, to create 3 vs 3 teams, but I'm looking to do until 22 (11 vs 11). Any ideas are welcomed.
{
        int dif1 = Math.abs((listaDeJugadores.get(0).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(1).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(2).getPuntaje())
                - (listaDeJugadores.get(3).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(4).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(5).getPuntaje()));
        int jugador1 = 0;
        int jugador2 = 1;
        int jugador3 = 2;
        int jugador4 = 3;
        int jugador5 = 4;
        int jugador6 = 5;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

//The two fors are to search the arrays. The iterador is to find the other three remaining positions to compare.
            for (int cont2 = 1; cont2 < listaDeJugadores.size() - 1; cont2++) {
                for (int cont3 = cont2 + 1; cont3 < listaDeJugadores.size(); cont3++) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    int iterador[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
                    int j = 1;
                    for (int i=0;i<iterador.length;i++)
                    {
                        //I look for the missing players to compare from the 6 possible
                        if (cont2==iterador[i]|cont3==iterador[i])
                        {
                            j++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c=b;
                            b=a;
                            a=j;
                            i--;
                            j++;
                        }
                    }

                    int dif = Math.abs((listaDeJugadores.get(0).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(cont2).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(cont3).getPuntaje())
                            - (listaDeJugadores.get(a).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(b).getPuntaje() + listaDeJugadores.get(c).getPuntaje()));
                    if (dif < dif1) {
                        dif = dif1;
                        jugador1 = 0;
                        jugador2 = cont2;
                        jugador3 = cont3;
                        jugador4 = a;
                        jugador5 = b;
                        jugador6 = c;
                    }
                }
        }
        //I add the best available sorted teams to EquipoBlanco or EquipoNegro.
        listaEquipoBlanco.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador1));
        listaEquipoBlanco.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador2));
        listaEquipoBlanco.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador3));
        listaEquipoNegro.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador4));
        listaEquipoNegro.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador5));
        listaEquipoNegro.add(listaDeJugadores.get(jugador6));

        team1.setText("Equipo Blanco: " + (listaEquipoBlanco.get(0).getPuntaje() + listaEquipoBlanco.get(1).getPuntaje() + listaEquipoBlanco.get(2).getPuntaje()));
        team2.setText("Equipo Negro: " + (listaEquipoNegro.get(0).getPuntaje() + listaEquipoNegro.get(1).getPuntaje() + listaEquipoNegro.get(2).getPuntaje()));
```

I think the code is ok, but when I try to run it, it won't open because it has really bad performance. I'm thinking I might have iterated to infinity or something similar, but also when I look at it and see fors inside of fors inside of fors I know something is wrong.

How can I make it run faster and have better performance?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at it and that inner for loop looks suspicious. I might be wrong without trying ( bad me), but it has a `i--;` in there and `i` is the loop index so of that happens all the time or often enough you will never exit that one.

That happens when this isn't true: `cont2==iterador[i]|cont3==iterador[i]` (bitwise or, should probably be logical or `||` by the way), Not sure that is guaranteed to be true at some point? Could go back and forth even perhaps. cont2 and contr3 doesn't change but `i` can change a little bit.

No protection for `i` to go below zero though either so could crash and burn (exception).